# ¿Cómo agregar el valor de una variable que contiene un entero a un string que es parte del atributo id de una etiqueta?

Tags: javascript

Mi consulta va relacionada a que tengo una variable de php y la paso a javascript porque quiero crear varias variables que me son necesarias ya que quiero leer información desde un archivo JSON hacer unas lecturas mediante `document.getElementById()`. En sí la variable que traigo desde php me indica el número de tuplas que hay en una tabla, ahora en un documento javascript en un bucle `for` quiero agregar esta variable que vendría a ser un contador al final de un id que ya tengo escrito.

La variable que traigo desde php es `num_items` y es utilizada en la parte condicional.

La estructura que manejo en javascript es:

```
function cargarDatosE() {
   const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.open('GET','info.json',true);
   xhttp.send();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          let datos =JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          for (var i = 0; i < num_items; i++) {
-->           let resI+string(i) = '';   
-->           document.getElementById('imgDG').src = datos.dgrafico[i].imagen;
-->           document.getElementById('imgDG').alt = datos.dgrafico[i].titulo;
-->           document.getElementById('ttlDG').innerText = datos.dgrafico[i].titulo;
-->           document.getElementById('precioDG').innerText = datos.dgrafico[1].precio;
-->           for (i+string(i) in datos.dgrafico[i].caract) {
-->               resI+string(i) += datos.dgrafico[0].caract[i+string(i)];
-->           }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Hasta el momento no he probado las líneas de código que tienen la **-->**, sin embargo, lo demás si funciona ya que en otros archivos utilizo las mismas líneas de código pero ya especificando las variables como también todo el atributo id, los índices.
Solo que estoy buscando en la página de MDN Web Docs acerca de lo que quiero hacer pero no he encontrado como crear las variables con los nombres que incluyen en este caso la variable "i" todavía.

**Alguien tiene alguna noción de lo que trato de hacer y que me pueda compartir su conocimiento?**

Answer (score 0):

No se el nombre de tu variable php, ni donde quieres ponerla, pero para insertar una variable php en código js, puedes hacer algo parecido a:

```
< ?php

var $myVarName = false;
var $msg = "";
$msg = "Este es un mensaje";
?>
```

Comment: la variable se llama "num_items" y la utilizo dentro del bucle for específicamente en la parte condicional